# selenium standalone server browsing internet very slow

Tags: java, performance, selenium, centos, phantomjs

I created a java application for running test using phantomjs and selenium standalone server on CentOS VPS, everything is working fine and I am able to take a test using RemoteWebDriver without any issue.

I decided to use CentOS VPS for my testing because my VPS internet speed is 35.00 mbps, so I thought my test will utilize those speed, but currently it is not utilizing the speed.

I also tried by setting proxy server on my VPS using squid and also working without any issue but again I am getting very slow browsing speed.

Example:

I have 4 mbps internet speed on my machine, so when I run the test on my local machine not using RemoteWebDriver it gives me 512 kbps browsing speed, that is what it should give.

On other hand my VPS has 35 mbps internet speed I thought running test on VPS will give good internet browsing speed, so I decided to use RemoteWebDriver to run my test, although I succeeded setting it up and running my test on VPS  by starting selenium standalone server on VPS and calling RemoteWebDriver on my local machine but I didn't the expected internet speed instead its slower than my local test speed.

I tried searching in google and SO too, but not found anything regarding it, as I don't know how to accomplish that so decided to ask a question at StackOverflow.

any help or suggestion would be a great help for me, thanks a lot in advance looking for help.